# Tracing source (Timeline, Group or Page) of url shared on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a simple servlet that just logs any requests. I was hopping to identify if a request came from Facebook Timeline, Group or Page, but, apart from the header **"Referer":"https://www.facebook.com/"**, I couldn't find anything telling me where that url came from (there's no arguments on request neither).

Is there any way of tracing the source of request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to user user_agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1
Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Comment: Do you mind explaining how identifying a crawler is gonna help me tracing back the source of share? Back in the days, facebook used to add parameters to the url telling where it came from. But I couldn't find anything like that anymore.